# Python Pandas: For Loop to drop rows from dataframes where values are the same in before/after cases

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, drop

I have 238 dataframes that look like this:

| Index | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a,1 | 10 | 10 |
| b,2 | 10 | 100 |
| c,3 | 100 | 100 |
| d,4 | 1000 | 100 |

I would like to have a for loop which would drop all of the rows where before and after values are the same (leave only those rows where they are different). Example

| Index | before | after |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b,2 | 10 | 100 |
| d,4 | 1000 | 100 |

Right now, I just have 238 of these:
onlydiffs_dfi = dfi[dfi['before'] != dfi['after']]

Which is obviously not great, and can be accomplished with a for loop but I but figure out how to write it. Please help!

Comment: Do your DFs come from csvs? You can put them in a list and iterate over the list.

Comment: no, I created them using this code (gifted from another stackoverflow genius): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73041300/use-python-pandas-for-loop-to-create-pivot-tables-for-each-column-in-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment129004997_73041300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list containing the dataframes and iterate:

```
df_list =[*list of dfs]

for df in df_list:
    new_df = df[df['before'] != df['after']]
```

Then you can append it to a new list... or whatever you want to do with it
If all your dfs are in a dictionary, you iterate as well just index into it:

```
df_dict = {key0:df0,key1:df1 ....}
for key,df in df_dict.items():
   new_df = df[df['before'] != df['after']]
```

or even less pythonic:

```
for key in df_dict.keys():
    df = df_dict[key]
    new_df = df[df['before'] != df['after']]
```

You can even convert you dictionary values to a list and use the first method:

```
df_list = list(df_dict.values())
```

Comment: Thank you I like this, it is simple - now another layer of complexity, what if all my dfs are in a dictionary?

Comment: you just do the same thing with slightly different syntax